# Replace keywords with variables

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a string which looks about like this:

```
"give %player% %id% %amount%"
```

And an object:

```
{player: "Abc", id: 3, amount: 4, ...}
```

How can I replace all Variables in the string ("%player%", "%id%", ...) with the value of the variables with the same name in the object? The variable names might change in various cases, so that should be changed automatically. Also, is there a way to kind of define a filter, like ignore all variables with a specific name?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Did you take a look at the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Freplace) method?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know how to replace keywords which are different and how to handle them as variables in the newSubStr-argument.

Comment: Look for sprintf() JavaScript implementations.

Comment: *"how to replace keywords which are different"* what does that mean? Different from what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`str.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) accepts a callback function as replacement. Together with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and groups, you can search for all occurrences of the stubstring `%...%`, get the value between the `%` and look up the corresponding property name in the object.

Example:

```
var data = {
   foo: 42;
};

"The answer is: %foo%".replace(/%([^%]+)%/g, function(match, prop) {
    return prop in data ? data[prop] : match;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! By keywords being different I just meant that they might vary so I don't want a switch construction that switches between given variable names. But your method works perfectly, thanks again!